# PHP based app/web login framework?

Tags: php, mysql, oauth, hmac

I currently have a very simple PHP based login system that works with android, iOS, and the web but I'd like to use something with a little more security.  My current setup simply passes the username, and the password in md5 format to authenticate against my DB.

Is there a framework people recommend using.  I've heard of oAuth and HMAC with PHP but I'm not sure if these are overkill for what I need.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Take your login script here [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and you will know if you need anymore security

Answer (score 2):

For starters, MD5 is not considered secure anymore.  It's just too easy to brute-force with modern hardware.

Secondly, if you're sending an MD5 over the wire & that is what you have in the database, you are effectively using the MD5 of the password as the password.  This means you're sending the unencrypted password over the wire.  Think about it - an attacker just needs to capture the MD5 and send it back if they want to break in - you are not getting any actual security from this.

Just send plaintext username and password over SSL.  Compare it against a server-side secure hash (bcrypt is considered the way to go these days) that's got a secret key merged in.  This will limit risk if your DB gets compromised.